# How can I animate buttons separately?

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations

I am new to programming and working on game with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I am trying to figure out how to animate all my buttons. Is there was a way to make all the buttons shiver around randomly or do I have to apply it separately?

This is how they are generated in my JavaScript file.

```
function generateButtons() {
  let buttonsHTML = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    .split('')
    .map(
      (letter) =>
        `
      <button
        class= "btn btn-lg btn-primary m-2"
        id='` +
        letter +
        `'
        onClick="handleGuess('` +
        letter +
        `')"
      >
        ` +
        letter +
        `
      </button>
    `
    )
    .join('');

  document.getElementById('keyboard').innerHTML = buttonsHTML;
}'''
```

Answer (score 1):

look at these examples:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_animate_buttons.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_shake_image.asp

very easy to put them together.